# Why does DNS return alternately old and new addresses when you change nameservers for a website move?

Tags: dns, website, hosting, nameserver

Registrars warn you that the process of moving a site (and changing nameservers to do so) can take up to 48 hours to propagate.  That's one thing - but why in the process of propagation does it work one minute and not the next?

Answer (score 0):

Because the other name servers in the world sync their zones on a schedule. When their timer is up, they refresh their information.

This timer is usually set to a value of several hours. Until **most** nameservers on the world (that care about the domain and have it cached) have refreshed their zones, you will get the old result.